# how to read one file from multiple folders?

Tags: r, directory

In R, if I have one folder called "main" which has 10 subfolders called from A,B,C...J, each sub folder has a .txt file, sub folder A has a 1.txt, subfolder B has a 2.txt, how can I read all this file without typing the name of each file ?

I used this code

```
data.path="C:/file/path/main"
files=list.files(path=data.path, recursive =T, pattern = "*.txt")
read_file= read.delim(files,header = TRUE, sep = "\t")
```

and this message appeared : No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

```
library(readr)

data.path <- "C:/file/path/main"
files <- list.files(path = data.path, pattern = "*.txt", full.names = TRUE)
Then you can use `lapply` function to apply `read_csv` to your files:

data <- lapply(files, read_csv)

You can also use `read_csv` in order to read text files.
```

Comment: you will have a list as a result of using lapply function but every element of this list is a data frame. So you can use the rbindlist function to turn it into a data frame and bind them row-wise:
`library(data.table)`
`rbindlist(data)`

Comment: thank you for your effort but it doesn't work

Comment: i have 285 txt file in 251 folder and i need just specific_name.txt file to save them as data frame so i type your code like this
files <- list.files(path = data.path, pattern = ".mirnas.quantification.txt")
data <- lapply(files, read_csv)
it give me data alist of (0)

Comment: I simulated your situation and by adding `recursive = TRUE ` to `list.files` function and dropping `pattern` argument I could read them all.